# In C++ `multimap`, how can I get efficiently a collection of the `mapped_type` elements without the duplicates?

Tags: c++, list, iterator, unique, multimap

I have a `std::multimap< int, std::string >` like that:

```
1 A
1 B
1 C
1 B
1 C
1 C
```

and I would like to get a collection of `mapped_type` elements with no duplicates, like that:

```
1 A
1 B
1 C
```

My solution is like this:

```
#include <map>
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   std::multimap< int, std::string > mm;
   mm.insert( std::make_pair(1,"A") );
   mm.insert( std::make_pair(1,"B") );
   mm.insert( std::make_pair(1,"C") );
   mm.insert( std::make_pair(1,"B") );
   mm.insert( std::make_pair(1,"C") );
   mm.insert( std::make_pair(1,"C") );

   auto range( mm.equal_range(1) );

   std::list< std::string > ss;
   std::transform(range.first, range.second, 
                  std::back_inserter(ss), 
                  [](const std::pair<int,std::string>& p) {
                      return p.second;
                  });
   ss.sort();
   ss.unique();
   return 0;
}
```

Is there any more efficient way to get the collection?

Comment: @Alon It's the key of the key-value pairs that you store in a map. If you're confused because having only ones seems unnecessary and wasteful, that's because this is a simplified example, that multimap may have different keys as well in pratice.

Comment: can't just do a set with a pair? do you want to store the duplicates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Algorithmically, this is already the most efficient way. Bulk operations like sort and unique almost always trump online operations like set-inserts by constant factors.

That said, it is usually recommended to stay away from node-based containers like list, map and set when performance is key. You could switch to `std::vector`, `std::sort` and `std::unique`, but in your example, that might not be faster, since moving around strings might actually be slower than rearranging list-nodes. If you have move-support and no small-string optimizations active, if might be worth a try.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `std::set`, which only allows unique values, instead of a `std::list`:

```
std::set<std::string> ss;
std::transform(range.first, range.second, 
               std::inserter(ss, ss.begin()), 
               [](const std::pair<int,std::string>& p) {
                   return p.second;
               });
```

Now you don't have to use `sort` or `unique`.

Comment: But it will be less efficient, since this is basically the online variant of what he does

Comment: @ltjax why? I think the running time is less than the OP's solution. OP's solution: ``n + nlogn + n``, this solution: ``nlogn``

Comment: You cannot really be that detailed about the running time, but it terms of big-Oh, you are correct, but also: O(n+nlogn+n) == O(nlogn). The constant factor in bulk operations is usually a lot better than with node based containters tho.

Comment: Your time is C1*N*log(N) while his is C2*(log(N)+2)*N - only his constant factor "C2" will most certainly be a lot smaller - so much that is will negate the effect of the additional passes.